# matplotlib bug after installing with pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda

On a server with 3 ***conda*** environments `base`, `rpy`, `front` I executed `pip install matplotlib` on the `base` environment and since then I have bugs in the other environments not showing the exact graphs I used to see (scripts didn't change at all).

Is there a way that when I tried to install something with pip and not with conda ruined something on the server regarding this package?

After finding out about the bug, I tried to uninstall the package from the `base` env with `pip uninstall matplotlib` but the bugs persist.

Comment: Do all the environments use the same Python version? Was Matplotlib already installed prior to the `pip install`? To answer your question, yes, in general [one should not use pip in **base**](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment). In particular, the `matplotlib` package in the Conda ecosystem is split into multiple packages, and includes precompiled (Cython) components that overwriting with a PyPI build may leave partially in place.

Comment: @merv Yes, all environemnts use python 3.6.
matplotlib wasn't installed on the environment `base` before I executed `pip install`.
Is there a way to revert these changes? Is rolling a directory back to a specific date possible?

Comment: Alternatively, I thought of trying to recreate this environment, so I executed `conda list` and got it in some file, can I create a conda environment from this list of packages?

Comment: I usually recommend `conda env export > env.yaml` then `conda env create -n newenv -f env.yaml`, especially if the environment has pip-installed packages.

Comment: As for reverting, once `pip` has been used, Conda's state representation may no longer accurately capture the actually environment state. However, it could be worth a try. You'd likely need to enable the config option `pip_interop_enabled` first, then use `conda list --revisions` to find a revision to revert to, and finally do `conda install --revision <n>` where `<n>` is the revision you want to attempt reverting to.